# Store String of Integers into an Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer, dynamic-allocation

```
void ReadReferenceStream(char * filename) {
    char buf[MAXCHAR];
    int i;
    char* np;

    inputfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(inputfile == NULL)
        printf("File is empty!\n");

    while((fgets(buf,MAXCHAR,inputfile)) != NULL) {
        if(buf[0] == '#' || buf[0] == '\n')
            continue;
    }

    np = strtok(buf," ");

    Pages = malloc(atoi(np)*sizeof(int));
```

That's all I have so far.

I need to first dynamically allocate space for my array (the variable 'np' is how many integers have to be in the array 'Pages'), which I hope I did correctly.

Then, I have skip any lines in the input text file that start with # or the NULL character.

Finally, I need to store the integers into the array Pages, with the exception of the first integer, which is the value for 'np'.

How can I alter my code to get it to work exactly as I have mentioned.  I got most of it, I am just struggling to get it to put the integers into the array.

Comment: You should replace one of your tags with a language tag instead.

Comment: The `if` statement is unnecessary.  All that loop does is keep going until `fgets` returns `NULL`.  `buf` is left with whatever the last string read was.

Comment: if `(inputfile == NULL)` then your program prints "File is empty!\n" and continues instead of stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have so far, and assuming `Pages` is defined like `int *Pages`, just read in the remaining integers:

```
    for (i = 0; np = strtok(NULL, " "); ++i) Pages[i] = atoi(np);
```